# Voltar para tela fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Boa noite Pessoal.
Tenho um main e 3 classes fragment.

Ao acessar o main, consigo deslizar para cada fragment corretamente.
Porém, em cada fragment tenho funcionalidades. Se eu acessar uma dessas funções e tentar voltar ele sempre abre o primeiro fragment.

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

**MainPager**

```
public class MainPager extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private Button buttonVoltar, buttonAnterior, buttonProximo;
private MenuPrimario menuPrimario;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpager);

    buttonVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVoltarPrincipal);
    buttonAnterior = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnterior);
    buttonProximo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProximo);

    buttonVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainPager.this, TelaInicial.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MenuPrimario.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MenuSecundario.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MenuTerciario.class.getName()));

    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainPager.this, TelaInicial.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**MenuPrimario**

```
public class MenuPrimario extends Fragment {

private LinearLayout containerTelefone, containerContato, containerMensagem, containerCamera;
private ImageView imgTelefone, imgContato, imgMensagem, imgCamera;
private TextView textTelefone, textContato, textMensagem, textCamera;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menuprimario, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    containerTelefone = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container_telefone);
    containerTelefone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AbrirTelefone();
        }
    });


    containerContato = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container_contato);
    containerContato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AbrirContato();
        }
    });


    containerMensagem = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container_mensagem);
    containerMensagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AbrirMensagem();
        }
    });

    containerCamera = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container_camera);
    containerCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AbrirCamera();
        }
    });

}
```

Os outros 2 fragment tem a mesma lógica.
Ao acessar qualquer função dos métodos, ele sempre volta para o primeiro fragment.

**Método Voltar**

```
public void VoltarAoMenu(View v) {// Metodo para voltar para MenuPrimario
    Intent VoltarAoMenu = new Intent(MenuContatos.this, MainPager.class);
    startActivity(VoltarAoMenu);
    finish();
}
```

Tem como verificar qual fragment está ativo? Se sim, irei alterar algumas imagens no MainPager.

Answer (score 0):

Estou imaginando que essas funcionalidades que você cita estão em outras activities. Então quando você deixa a Activity principal (que tem o pager) ela é destruída e, quando você volta pra ela, é recriada (e no caso do pager, carrega o primeiro Fragment). Assim é o ciclo de vida de Activity.

O que dá pra fazer é salvar a posição do pager antes da Activity ser destruída (método onSaveInstanceState) e restaurá-lo no onCreate.

Faz dessa forma:

1) Declare o seu pager fora do OnCreate.

```
ViewPager pager;
```

2) Declare o método OnSaveInstante para salvar a posição do Pager

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt(pager.getCurrentItem(), "pagerPosition");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

3) Dentro do OnCreate, no final, restaure a posição do pager:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    pager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("pagerPosition"));
```

Comment: Preciso salvar e restaurar no MainPager?

Comment: Sim, no MainPager. Estou entendendo que é a Activity principal do programa.

Comment: Implementei o seguinte método: @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {

        outState.putSerializable("list", (Serializable) fragments);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

Comment: E recuperei no onCreate: if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            fragments = (List<Fragment>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
        } . Mas continua mesma coisa.

Comment: Você tem que salvar nessa variável savedInstanceStace um inteiro simples, que é a posição do Pager, que você pega pelo método   getCurrentItem()  do Pager. Depois na hora de restaurar é só passar o valor salvo no método setCurrentItem(position) do pager, que ele vai listar a página que estava.

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Vê se funciona.

Comment: Agora fez mais sentido. Porém ainda não funcionou. Ele volta para o primeiro fragment. Eu adiciona na lista de fragmentos se saveInstanceState for null, certo?